# Rangy: New method for getting selected nodes

Tags: javascript, rangy

It looks like the newest Alpha version of rangy has deprecated the createNodeIterator() method and replaced it with a more general createIterator() instead. It seems the syntax for using it is a bit different as well.

Say a user has gone through and made multiple selections to a document and applied CSS classes to those selections. My goal is make sure a user is unable to make overlapping selections to text that already has a rangy-applied CSS class.

Could I still do this with the createIterator function? Is there a built-in function that could help me with this otherwise?

Comment: Why don't you use getNodes()? It returns a node collection you want.

Comment: @taggon Good call. I'll post code for my solution

Comment: Apologies for not fully documenting all this yet.

Answer (score 2):

I went with this solution:

```
var isHighlighted = false,
range = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

var it = range.getNodes([3], function(node) {
    return node.parentNode.tagName == 'SPAN' && node.parentNode.className == 'highlight';
});

if (it.length > 0)
    isHighlighted = true;

return isHighlighted;
```

Comment: One of the things that tripped me up was the [3] parameter. That's just an enum for the TEXT_NODE node type:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType